# How can I delete numbers and characters from my date and convert a character column to a date column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the column name perioden. This column contains the date but it is written in this format: 2010JJ00, 2011JJ00, 2012JJ00, 2013JJ00 etc..
This column is also a character when I look at the structure. I've tried multiple solutions but so far am still stuck, my qeustion is how can I convert this column to a date and how do I remove the JJ00 part so that you only see the year format of the column.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub("JJ00", "", df$perioden))` where `df` is the name of your data frame

Comment: The strings aren't sufficiently date-like to be able to do that. If `JJ` hints at a month, then we still need a day (`00` doesn't work). If not, then we need both a month and a day. What `Date` values are you expecting for those strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. Using `gsub()` to remove the non desired text (as said by @AllanCameron) and then format to date using `paste0()` to add the day and month, and `as.Date()` for date transformation:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Date=c('2010JJ00', '2011JJ00', '2012JJ00', '2013JJ00'),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Remove string
df$Date <- gsub('JJ00','',df$Date)
#Format to date, you will need a day and month
df$Date2 <- as.Date(paste0(df$Date,'-01-01'))
```

Output:

```
  Date      Date2
1 2010 2010-01-01
2 2011 2011-01-01
3 2012 2012-01-01
4 2013 2013-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ymd` with `truncated` option

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
ymd(str_remove(df$Date, 'JJ\\d+'), truncated = 2)
#[1] "2010-01-01" "2011-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2013-01-01"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c('2010JJ00', '2011JJ00', '2012JJ00', '2013JJ00'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```